# Calling Julia macro with runtime-dependent argument

Tags: macros, runtime, metaprogramming, julia

I would like to call a macro in a Julia package (`@defNLExpr` in JuMP) using an argument that is runtime dependent. The argument is an expression that depends on the runtime parameter `n`. The only way that I can think of doing this is something like the following:

```
macro macro1(x)
  y=length(x.args);
  return esc(:(k=$y-1))
end

macro macro2(n)
  x="0";
  for i=1:n
    x="$x+$i"
  end
  x=parse(x);
  return :(@macro1($x))
end

n=rand(1:3)
println(n)
if (n==1)
  @macro2(1)
elseif (n==2)
  @macro2(2)
elseif (n==3)
  @macro2(3)
else
  error("expected n in 1:3")
end
println(k)
```

Here I have assumed that my runtime `n` will always be in the range 1-3. I use `macro2` to build-up all possible expressions for these different possible values of `n`, and call the external macro (which I have replaced by the simplified `macro1` here) for each of them. The calls to `macro1` are in `if` statements, so only the correct one (determined from the value of `n` at runtime) will actually be executed.

Although this seems to work, is there a more efficient way of achieving this?

Comment: Usually runtime dependent code generation comes through `@generated` functions.  You should check them out in [the docs](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/manual/metaprogramming/#generated-functions)

Comment: I believe `@generated` functions only have access to the type of their arguments, and so the value `n` would not be known.

Comment: You are right that you `@generated` works on types of arguments, but you can "trick" the system into working for you. If you create a type with no fields, but one type parameter `n`, you can then use `@generated` to do it. I haven't thought about your application, so I can't say I recommend this approach, but [here's](https://github.com/spencerlyon2/CompEcon.jl/blob/master/src/complete.jl) an example that does this. Notice that I needed `d` loops (`d` is a function argument). So I shoved that runtime _value_ `d` in as the type parameter on `Degree` and let `@generated` work on `Degree{d}`

Comment: Ugly but clever. I haven't been able to get it to work in my case yet - I think it is expanding the macro before it generates the function, so `n` is still just a symbol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that you might be looking for [eval](http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/stdlib/base/#Base.eval)? Be aware that it should be used with care though, and that it not very fast since it has to income the compiler each time it is called.

If it's a limitation to you that it evaluates the expression in global scope then, there are some ways to work around that.

Comment: `eval` does indeed seem to work in my example (replace all of the conditionals in my example (`if (n==1)`...`end`) with `eval(:(@macro2($n)))` and you get the same result). I didn't use it in my actual code both because I thought running in global scope would be problematic, and because I wasn't sure that `eval' would cause the expanding of the macro to be delayed to runtime. I would be grateful if you could point to a code example or description that explains how to work around the global scope issue.

Comment: `eval` definitely doesn't do anything with the AST until runtime. When it comes to global scope, one way to work around it is to `eval` a function definition instead, and then call that. Eg `f = eval( :( ()->@(macro2($n); return k) ) ); k = f ()`. This might even allow you to add some normal arguments to the function and reuse it for cases when `n` is the same.

Comment: I'll accept your answer, as it does work for my simple example above, but unfortunately trying to get it to work in the real code proved too much for me, so I will just use my simple, but inelegant, method with the `if` statements. Hopefully there will eventually be a clean way of running `eval` with local scope.